# DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories() and attributes

Tags: .net, file-io, attributes, directoryinfo, getdirectories

I am using `DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories()` recursively to find the all the sub-directories under a given path.
However, I want to exclude the System folders and there is no clear way for that.
In FindFirstFile/FindNextFile things were clearer with the attributes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@rslite is right, .NET doesn't give such filtering out-of-box, but it's not hard to implement:

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetNonSystemDirs(string path)
{
    var dirs = from d in Directory.GetDirectories(path)
               let inf = new DirectoryInfo(d)
               where (inf.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) == 0
               select d;

    foreach (var dir in dirs)
    {
        yield return dir;
        foreach (var subDir in GetNonSystemDirs(dir))
        {
            yield return subDir;
        }
    }
}
```

MSDN links:

[FileSystemInfo.Attributes Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.attributes.aspx)

[FileAttributes Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

This is a great example of a scenario where Linq and extension methods make things really clean and easy.

```
public static DirectoryInfo[] GetNonSystemDirectories(
    this DirectoryInfo directory,
    string searchPattern,
    SearchOption searchOption)
{
    return directory.GetDirectories(searchPattern, searchOption)
        .Where(subDir => (subDir.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) == 0)
        .ToArray();
}
```

If you're building a .net v2 application, then you can use [LinqBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.html) to give you access to all the cool Linq to objects methods (like Where() and ToArray() above).

**Edit**

In .net v4 you'd use [EnumerateDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratedirectories.aspx) instead of [GetDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.getdirectories.aspx) which allows you to iterate over the results without building an array in memory first.

```
public static IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> EnumerateNonSystemDirectories(
    this DirectoryInfo directory,
    string searchPattern,
    SearchOption searchOption)
{
    return directory.EnumerateDirectories(searchPattern, searchOption)
        .Where(subDir => (subDir.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) == 0);
}
```

Comment: Directory.GetDirectories returns strings, how do you get Attributes from it? :)

Comment: @aku I'm using the DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories instance method, not the Directory.GetDirectories static one.

Comment: Not as efficient/usable as creating a true recursive iterator using yield return.   On big directory hierarchies using SearchOption.AllDirectories is not so good.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably have to loop through the results and reject those with the attributes that you don't want (use the Attributes property).

Answer (score 0):

Using the ultimate Sweet Linq

```
 IEnumerable<string> directories = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetDirectories().Where(a => (a.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) == 0).Select(a => a.FullName);
```